# Grouping of variables in XSLT 2.0

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0, xslt-grouping

For each `<LineDetail>` node that has the same value of `<CtryCd>` and populates 1 `<LineDetail>` with the summation of `<Amt>`.
But, I need to check also the `<SI>` and `<TI>` node. The output tag of the summation will be based from the `<SI>` and `<TI>`
node. The `<Amt1>` will generate if the value of `<SI>` and `<TI>` are both false, while `<Amt2>` will generate if the value of `<SI>` is true and `<TI>` is false.
I created an XSLT and already got the summation. But there's still something missing in my output.

**This is a sample XML:**

```
<Record>
<Data>
    <Process>
        <Header>
            <ID>22-BBB</ID>
            <Date>2017-02-14</Date>
            <ContactName>Abegail</ContactName>
            <!-- some other elements -->
        </Header>
        <Detail>
            <ID>22-CCC</ID>
            <RequestedDate>2017-02-14</RequestedDate>
            <!-- some other elements -->
            <LineDetail>
                <CtryCd>AF</CtryCd>
                <SI>false</SI>
                <TI>false</TI>
                <Amt>11.11</Amt>
            </LineDetail>
            <LineDetail>
                <CtryCd>SE</CtryCd>
                <SI>true</SI>
                <TI>false</TI>
                <Amt>22.22</Amt>
            </LineDetail>
            <LineDetail>
                <CtryCd>AF</CtryCd>
                <SI>false</SI>
                <TI>false</TI>
                <Amt>33.33</Amt>
            </LineDetail>
            <LineDetail>
                <CtryCd>AF</CtryCd>
                <SI>true</SI>
                <TI>false</TI>
                <Amt>55.55</Amt>
            </LineDetail>       
        </Detail>
    </Process>
</Data>
</Record>
```

**Generated output:**

```
<Record>
<Data>
    <Process>
        <Header>
            <ID>22-BBB</ID>
            <Date>2017-02-14</Date>
            <ContactName>Abegail</ContactName>
            <!-- some other elements -->
        </Header>
        <Detail>
            <LineDetail>
                <CtryCd>AF</CtryCd>
                <Amt1>99.99</Amt1>
            </LineDetail>
        </Detail>
        <Detail>
            <LineDetail>
                <C<Amt2>22.22</Amt2>
            </LineDetail>
        </Detail>
    </Process>
</Data>
</Record>
```

**Expected output:**

```
<Record>
<Data>
    <Process>
        <Header>
            <ID>22-BBB</ID>
            <Date>2017-02-14</Date>
            <ContactName>Abegail</ContactName>
            <!-- some other elements -->
        </Header>
        <Detail>
            <ID>22-CCC</ID>
            <RequestedDate>2017-02-14</RequestedDate>
            <!-- some other elements -->
            <LineDetail>
                <CtryCd>AF</CtryCd>
                <Amt1>44.44</<Amt1>
                <Amt2>55.55</Amt2>
            </LineDetail>
            <LineDetail>
                <CtryCd>SE</CtryCd>
                <Amt1>0</<Amt1>
                <Amt2>22.22</Amt2>
            </LineDetail>           
        </Detail>
    </Process>
</Data>
</Record>
```

**XSLT:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
<xsl:key name="CtryCd" match="LineDetail" use="CtryCd"/>
<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="Detail">
    <xsl:for-each-group select="LineDetail" group-by="CtryCd">
        <Detail>
            <LineDetail>
                <CtryCd>
                    <xsl:value-of select="CtryCd"/>
                </CtryCd>
                <xsl:if test="lower-case(SI)='false' and lower-case(TI)='false'">
                    <Amt1>
                        <xsl:value-of select="sum(current-group()/Amt)"/>
                    </Amt1>
                <xsl:if test="lower-case(SI)='true' and lower-case(TI)='false'">
                    <Amt2>
                        <xsl:value-of select="sum(current-group()/Amt)"/>
                    </Amt2>
                </xsl:if>
                </xsl:if>
                <xsl:if test="lower-case(SI)='true' and lower-case(TI)='false'">
                    <Amt2>
                        <xsl:value-of select="sum(current-group()/Amt)"/>
                    </Amt2>
                </xsl:if>
            </LineDetail>
        </Detail>
    </xsl:for-each-group>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You current if condition will only check the first item in the group. You really need it to be part of the actual sum statement, as a condition on each node on the group.

```
<Amt1>
    <xsl:value-of select="sum(current-group()[lower-case(SI)='false' and lower-case(TI)='false']/Amt)"/>
</Amt1>
```

You would then have a similar statement for the `Amt2`, testing for "true" and "false"

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:key name="CtryCd" match="LineDetail" use="CtryCd"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Detail">
    <xsl:for-each-group select="LineDetail" group-by="CtryCd">
        <Detail>
            <LineDetail>
                <CtryCd>
                    <xsl:value-of select="CtryCd"/>
                </CtryCd>
                <Amt1>
                    <xsl:value-of select="sum(current-group()[lower-case(SI)='false' and lower-case(TI)='false']/Amt)"/>
                </Amt1>
                <Amt2>
                    <xsl:value-of select="sum(current-group()[lower-case(SI)='true' and lower-case(TI)='false']/Amt)"/>
                </Amt2>
            </LineDetail>
        </Detail>
    </xsl:for-each-group>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Got it. Thank you so much.